# How to set a variable value and start running from that in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, watch

I run a program step by step with monitoring variable's value by watch in `Netbeans`.
How can I start the running  of the program from a special value for a variable.

For example i have this  simple code just for testing:
For saving time i want to see the changes of  the program after the value of i reaches 25(i=25).

Using Run Debug>Run to cursor or f4 to go to this line in program.then the program starts from i=0 , but i don,t need to see  the changes before i=25.

```
public class DebugCondition {
private static void TestMethod()
{
            for(int i=0; i<= 29 ; i++)
            15.    System.out.print("i");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
 18.    TestMethod();
    }
}
```

What I do:
1. click on line 15.

2. define conditional breakpoint for that line by i>=25.
3. click on line 18 , then press F4.
4. Press F7 to go to method, then press F8 to debug body of method.
5. Result in watch: at first I starts from 0 .
   [image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe a conditional breakpoint can help?

Comment: A breakpoint is a mark in the source code that indicates the debugger to stop when the execution reach it. but i want to start  run with a special value of variable.

Comment: Not sure what is the question then. Do you want to set a variable to a value that you define outside of your program? Is so, there are many ways to do so, for instance, command line arguments, environment variables, properties, etc.

Comment: I do not often debug, and use the dumb way: `if (i == 25) { [breakpoint] }`. Did you try **Debug / New Watch** `i == 25`?

Comment: Just add a condition to the breakpoint so it stops only when `i == 25`

Comment: @Joop i==25?? it doesn,t return meaningful result !!

Comment: @Max:Thanks but I want to  "Start" from i==25 not stop.

Answer (score 1):

On Netbeans Menu Bar select `Debug -> New Breakpoint...` or `CTRL + SHIFT + F8`

[image]

And then fill the form:

1. Choose `Line` for `Breakpoint Type`.
2. Enter the `Line Number` for an example 19 is `System.out.println(i)`.
3. Check `Break when hit count`, choose `is greater than` and enter the number where you want to start first or check the `Condition` and put `i >= 25`.
4. Click `OK`

[image]

```
public class DebugCondition {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

It will start to debug at `i = 25` to `i = 30`.

## **Update:**

Make sure when you try to use the debug condition the breakpoint icon not a pink square (see picture bellow):

[image]

Not like this (a pink square breakpoint icon):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer.But my question is not that.In your example: i want to start to run (Not stop)from i=2. Is my question vague  ?

Comment: That is just an example, if you want to implement to your problem than set the `i` to 26.

Comment: @SaraBony: Already update my answer base on your problem, hope you understand mine...

Comment: Thanks. remains a problem yet.When i taste it for first time it work. But debugging next times did not work. do you have any idea?

Comment: No, i think that i know what,s  happened:when the breakpoint line is placed in Main method, it works well . But "For" loop   is placed in a method and i use F4 to debug from that line of method.t?Is there any other way?

Comment: @SaraBony: Maybe the problem is in the line that call your method that has loop inside. Try to debug inside your main method and push `F7` to go inside the method. Make sure that in your main method already call your loop method.

Comment: @SaraBony: Yes, very hard for me to trace the problem in here. If you don't mind please post some code in your question so we can analyze it.

Comment: It is strange thing.The code is simple, I just right it for testing.
Here is the code:

Comment: @SaraBony: In the `New Breakpoint` form, already fill the `Line number` with 5?

Comment: No , i attach the picture in main post.

Comment: Thanks, you right, its the problem. But i don,t know how i can do that, when i put condition breakpoint, that line became pink.sometimes its color became pink and sometimes no, i can not understand what affect on its color.